# Rotary Evaporator Cleaning

Tags: safety, solvents

I am using a rotary evaporator ('rotovap') in my lab mainly with dichloromethane as a solvent.

Usually between experiments I clean the receiving and boiling flasks with a brush using soap and water and finally rinse with alcohol.
For the condenser I try to do the same, but it is next to impossible to brush the water serpentine.

I want to try and distil some coffee and tea for consumption, but I am afraid of any possible contaminants.

What is an efficient and safe method to clean the glassware?

Comment: I personally think that doing food preparation using non-dedicated lab equipment is a *really bad idea*, irrespective of the experience and skill of the person doing it.

Comment: Agreed! My advice for anyone who wants to use lab equipment that previously held experiments for food is **don't**. Even if you were a food chemist, it is still a good idea to separate work and lunch.

Comment: That's one of the first safety rules: do not eat in the lab.

Comment: You already have 3 comments to this effect, but it just can't be overstated.  **Please *don't* use labware to prepare consumables.**  We want you here in the future!

Comment: OK, you guys are pretty convincing. No food preparation or consumption in the lab!

Answer (score 3):

There's no further need to comment on the **coffee maker**, but you might give the following cleaning method for the condenser and the rotation tube a try:

*Note that you might want to first check whether this is in accordance with local safety regulations!*

- Take a small or medium-sized (max. 500 mL) 2-neck flask (NS29 socket connects to the rotavap, NS14.5 socket is for your thumb) and fill it with max. 250 mL acetone
- Hook it up to the rotavap, support it with your hand
- No spinning :D
- Start the vacuum pump
- Close the NS14.5 socket with your thumb
- Watch the acetone starting to boil under reduce pressure
- Rapidly remove your thumb from from the socket and let the acetone "spit" all through the rotavap

Comment: Also works quite well with a Schlenk-Flask and higher boiling solvents.